# Change the background color of a value if it has been modified

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, workflow

So I have a SharePoint list and I implemented a flow that sends me an email if a value in a certain column has been changed. However, I have many columns and I was wondering if there is a way to change the background color of an item that has recently been edited? I just want to easily scroll through the list and be able to see in red, what values have been edited in the last 24 hours or so. is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**You can implement your design through MS Flow and JSON.**

**Please the following steps:**

**Step1.Create a Choice column named "Status" in your list**

[image]

**Step2.Create a MS Flow for your list**

a) Add a Trigger "**When an item is created or modified**"
[image]

b) Add an Action "**Get item**"
[image]

c) Add an Action "**Send an email (V2)**"
[image]

d) Add a Control "Condition"

- `(Get item)Modified is greater than or equal to addDays(utcNow(),-1)`

[image]

- **If yes**

Add an Action "**Update item**". Change Status value is "**Edit in the last 24 hours**"

[image]

- **If not**

Add an Action "**Update item**". Change Status value is "**Edit more than 24 hours**"

[image]

e) **Save** and **Test** it
[image]

**Step3.View Formatting**

**Use below JSON code to color the rows in your list:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "additionalRowClass": "=if([$Status] == 'No Changing','sp-css-backgroundColor-noFill',if([$Status] == 'Edit in the last 24 hours','sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground50','sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground27'))"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the entire row changes color when it has been edited. But is there anyway instead of the whole row, I can have just the single value change color? Basically highlight the value that was changed in the row.

Comment: Hi, Mik. I'm sorry, I cannot currently implement how to highlight the value changed in the row. If there is a solution in the future, I will share with you as soon as possible. Have a nice day!